# ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy'] on centos 7

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, flask, mod-wsgi

I have a virtualenv that holds all my Flask packages, I have Pandas and NumPy installed when I activate the environment Pandas and NumPy works just fine. When I try to use WSGI and `activate_this.py` I get the error,

ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

So after a lot more digging around, I think wsgi is running with python2.7 and not python3, so all the script imports fail.

Any suggestions on how  I can get mod_wsgi to work with packages for python3.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having a similar issue but I'm using Django.